# HTML/CSS Consulta / Error creando header en página web

Tags: html, css

Buenas gente,

Estoy realizando un proyecto para la universidad, creando una página web. Estoy creando el header, quiero organizarlo de la siguiente manera:

[image: Boceto header]
Como ven el header se compone de 3 partes:

En la parte de la izquierda, #logo_pagina estaría el logo de la pagina.

A su derecha, el resto del header, estaría dividido en 2 partes:

-En la superior estaría el titulo de la pagina y a su derecha link a distintas redes sociales (serían simplemente los iconos de facebook, twitter etc. y al pinchar enlazaría con estas páginas).

-En cuanto a la parte inferior estaría el nav donde estarían los distintos enlaces dentro de la página.

Habia pensado en hacerlo en 2 bloques, uno que contenga el logo_pagina, y otro todo el bloque de la derecha, y a su vez el bloque de la derecha, tenga 2 partes, una con el título y links, y otra con el nav.

Les adjunto el codigo html:

```css
header {
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #141414;
}

#header_logo {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
}

#header_div{
 display:inline-block;
 width: calc(100% - 305px);
 height: 100%;
 
}

#header_div #header_title{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
}

#header_div h1{
 display: inline;
}

#header_div #social_networks li{
 list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}

#header_div nav{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px
}
```

```html
<header>
 <img id="header_logo" src="/img/logo.png"/>
 <div id="header_div">
  <div id="header_title">
   <h1>TITULO PAGINA</h1>
   <ul id="social_networks">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <nav></nav>
 </div>
</header>
```

Tengo un problema que no se porque el segundo bloque, al que llamo #header_div, cuando tiene contenido, se desplaza el bloque hacia abajo.

El nav aun no tiene contendio, porque me he encontrado con el error antes de darle contenido, pero lo que contendría sería algo como la imagen.

¿Puede ser porque lo he puesto como inline-block?

¿Creen que sería mejor opción utilizar position para ir ordando mejor los bloques? ¿O tiene algún error mi código por el que no funciona correctamente?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Si tienen cualquier duda sobre el código, se la responderé encantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa `float:left` y `float:right`, los cuales son para ordenar a la parte izquierda y derecha de la pagina respectivamente.

```css
header {
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #141414;
}

#header_logo {
 float:left;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 border-right: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
}

#header_div{
    float:right;
 width: calc(100% - 305px);
 height: 100%;
}

#header_div #header_title{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
    color:#fff;
}

#header_div h1{
 display: inline;
}

#header_div #social_networks li{
 list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <img id="header_logo" src="/img/logo.png"/>
 <div id="header_div">
  <div id="header_title">
   <h1>TITULO PAGINA</h1>
   <ul id="social_networks">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <nav></nav>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Si! perfecto, era ese el error que tenía, no conocía las propiedades float. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, has solucionado mi problema.

Comment: @AlbertoFernandez que alegria poder haberte ayudado, y bienvenido a la comunidad.